# Is it safe to delete elements when iterating through a storage map in Substrate?

Tags: storage

In my pallet, I have a `StorageDoubleMap` called `MyDoubleMap`. I want to delete all the kv pairs under `key1`. So I may write the code like below:

```
for (key2, _value) in MyDoubleMap::<T>::iter_prefix(key1) {
    MyDoubleMap::<T>::remove(key1, key2);
}
```

Apparently the map was changed during the iteration. Will it be problematic?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the [docs](https://docs.rs/frame-support/latest/frame_support/storage/trait.IterableStorageDoubleMap.html#tymethod.iter_prefix) are mentioning, you will get undefined results. If you want to remove all these elements, you should directly use [`drain_prefix`](https://docs.rs/frame-support/latest/frame_support/storage/trait.IterableStorageDoubleMap.html#tymethod.drain_prefix) as this will give you directly what you want.

Comment: Is the same true for mutating the StorageItem? I.e. `set`, or `insert`?

Comment: The docs explicitly mention "adding". So, yes insert is also problematic. However, setting should be fine.